# Align both image and UILabel of the UIButton in the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I currently have : 
[image]

using this code:

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
button.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image]

Where the image and UILabel should be on the left side of the UIButton, not in the middle.

Comment: You can set image and title inset from size inspector

Comment: you can set HorizontalAlignment of button

Comment: Better solution is create UIView and add items as subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `contentHorizontalAlignment` property.

**Objective-C**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

**Swift**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Comment: there is no .left in objective - c.

Answer (score 0):

**To done this in Interface Builder you just need to change "alignment" property....**

**1.In attribute inspector of button change alignment Property to first option**

[image]

**2. this will be your output**

[image]

**3.if you want some space between image and title you can give from size inspector (just give some space in left property of title insets)**

[image]

**4.Final Output**

[image]